# How to use creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW with subprocess.run?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, cygwin

I'm trying to create a simple python/tkinter UI to run cygwin commands from Windows.

To avoid getting a command window, I'm starting my python script with pythonw.exe.

Here's the code that runs the cygwin command:

```py
def exec_ls():
    clear_log(log)
    print_log(log, "*** Running ls -lsa ***\n")
    s = subprocess.run(
        ["C:/cygwin/bin/ksh.exe", "-c", ". /etc/profile; ls -1 c:/test"],
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=STDOUT,
    )
    print_log(log, s.stdout)
    print_log(log, "\n*** END ***")
```

This runs successfully, but when exec_ls() is invoked, an empty command window flashes.

To remove the occurrence of this window, I tried to use creationflags as follows:

```py
def exec_ls():
    clear_log(log)
    print_log(log, "*** Running ls -lsa ***\n")
    s = subprocess.run(
        ["C:/cygwin/bin/ksh.exe", "-c", ". /etc/profile; ls -1 c:/test"],
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=STDOUT,
        creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
    )
    print_log(log, s.stdout)
    print_log(log, "\n*** END ***")
```

But then I don't get the command window, but the command doesn't run either (no output).

What did I do wrong?

Best regards

Comment: It might be that cygwin programs don't support running without a console/window.

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue: the import of CREATE_NO_WINDOW was missing, but as there was no command window I could not see to corresponding error message.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

I found it by running my script with pythonw.exe from a command window rather than from the shortcut I created.